# How to display multiple selected values from a dropdown in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, multi-select

I'm new to React and I wanted to create a dropdown which can select multiple values. For that I used the react-select plugin. In my React dev tool the selected values are getting stored but I'm not able to display all the selected values.
Any help is highly appreciated.
TIA

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
    { value: 'React', label: 'React' },
    { value: 'Vue', label: 'Vue' },
    { value: 'Angular', label: 'Angular' },
    { value: 'Java', label: 'Java' },
  ]

    const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = (skill) => {
        setSkills({skill})
        console.log("skills", skill);
    }
    
    return (
        <>
           <h2>Please select all your skills</h2>
             <form>
                 <Select 
                    options={options} 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    isMulti={true}
                    value={value}
                 />
                <button>Next</button> 
            </form>

        </>
    )
}

export default UserSkills;
```

When I'm commenting isMulti prop, I'm getting that one selected value, but I'm not getting anything with isMulti prop.

Comment: you are passing `value` prop, whic will assign the value, instead you need to pass `options` prop which lists all choices for the select. You can refer [getting started](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started) code in the docs

Answer (score 1):

You are controlling the `Select` component by giving it a `value`, and since you are not updating `value` in the `handleChange` function it will not be updated.

You could use the `skills` array as `value` instead and it will update as expected.

[**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-black-km7rn?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const options = [
  { value: "React", label: "React" },
  { value: "Vue", label: "Vue" },
  { value: "Angular", label: "Angular" },
  { value: "Java", label: "Java" }
];

function UserSkills() {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (skills) => {
    setSkills(skills || []);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Please select all your skills</h2>
      <form>
        <Select
          options={options}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={skills}
          isMulti
        />
        <button>Next</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default UserSkills;
```